# Ansible with a rotating sudo password

Tags: ansible

I have a system that has a rotating token based sudo password that changes every 30 seconds or so.  I'm using Ansible with privilege escalation.  I know I can pass in the `--ask-su-pass` option - but the problem I've run into is at the time of asking the password is one thing - yet it changes by the time Ansible actually attempts to sudo.

Is there a way to get prompted at the time of `sudo`-ing?

### Ansible Script

```
---
- name: Install & Setup Docker
  hosts: ece
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: Install Required Packages
      yum:
        name:
          - "yum-utils"
          - "device-mapper-persistent-data"
          - "lvm2"
        state: latest
      register: yum_result

    - debug:
        var: yum_result
        verbosity: 2
```

What happens when I run:

> PLAY [Install & Setup Docker]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
>   ********************************************************************************************************************************************************* fatal: [xxxx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr":
>   "Shared connection to xxxx closed.\r\n", "module_stdout":
>   "sudo: a password is required\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee
>   stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
>           to retry, use: --limit

So obviously I need a password for `sudo`.  The problem is the sudo password is a rotating password so every 30 seconds or so it changes

I can use the `--ask-su-pass` flag to enter a sudo password - but by the time i get to the first time its used i get:

> fatal: [xxxx]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Incorrect sudo password"}

because the password has since changed since I've entered it.  Trying to figure out if i can get a prompt at the point where its trying to enter the `sudo` password on the remote system

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but running a "sudo command" shell task without privilege escalation will prompt just at the moment of execution

Comment: Correct - but Ansible prompts at startup for a sudo password - not actually at escalation point - in which case the initial password I've entered seems to no longer be valid - because the token has changed

Comment: What I meant is that you can remove the `become: true` and replace the yum entry (which requires privileges) with a `shell: "sudo yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2" and it should bring you with the prompt asking for sudo password just at running time. Dirty hack though.